# How to integrate webform into multi form wizard into drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-webform, drupal-ctools

I am trying to integrate webform into multiform wizard (CTOOLS MULTISTEP WIZARD) in D7 but its not working, I don't have any idea how to integrate it (I am creating my own multi-form wizard in that i want to integrate webform) the following steps need to be followed:

```
1st step: registration(where we can fill some details).
2nd step: webform(where we can create a webform by drag and drop).
3rd step: some other form.
```

if it is not possible to integrate a webform into multi-form wizard then is there any alternate solution to do the same like wizard format?

Comment: Please elaborate the steps you followed.

Comment: Not answering your question, but the 'pagebreak' component from the webform module provides a multi-step functionality out of the box. Not sure if there is something that ctools multiform wizard offers that webform pagebreak doesn't though. Webform does depend on ctools for some of its functionality (see the .info file).